# @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome and unicode

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am upgrading font-awesome in my angular application earlier we were having hardcoded the URL of font-awesome (from CDN ) in style.scss file, now we got to have an angular package which is as below:

ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@3.0.0 and also similar SVG icons.

and we have changed the approach from
`<i class="fa fa-lock"><i>` to `<fa-icon icon="faLock"></fa-icon>`

Now the challenging stuff here is that in my existing application we have used `unicode` as below:

```
ui li:before {
content: '\f138';
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

I have changed the above to below

```
ui li:before {
    content: '\f01';
    font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free;
    }
```

but icons are not coming up, do we still need to define the .css file in angular.json to work for Unicode (the path of fort-awesome of node_modules )?

Please note that `my version of` fortawesome`supports`font-awesome version 5+`.

ADDED packages

```
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",

Angular version :6;
```

Comment: Hello, could share the exact packages you installed ? I use the angular-fontawesome library, and by default it produces svg icons, this is the recommended way : https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/angular. Solving your issue will depend on how you did your setup.

Comment: I have implemented the angular setup as stated in official doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome, Please see my original post for package version

Comment: Oh, I see you mention `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@3.0.0` but that must be a typo, since the lib is still around 0.1.x. Anyway, you can't rely on `Font-Family` because it's now SVG. I guess you should either load the CSS version as well, or migrate your old icons.

Comment: can you please little specific about your saying.  "it's now SVG. I guess you should either load the CSS version as well, or migrate your old icons."

Comment: If I'm correct, you would have to install the whole CSS package like so : https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/setup/use-package-managers and then don't forget to reference the proper assets : https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/setup/use-package-managers#next-steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you inspect your code where you use you new icons, you should see something like that :
[image]

That means that you don't have the css way to display FA icons :

```css
.fa, .fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

So you can't use the unicode trick to display an icon anymore.
Unless, on top of the angular svg FA library, you install the "web" way :
https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/setup/get-started. You will then have a regular `font-family` that you will be able to use.

Tell me if the part about the SVG makes sense to you if I expressed it correctly.
Cheers.

Comment: so do you mean we need to give reference in angular.json for fortawesome ? and also we can use both <fa-icon> way and unicode way togather ?

Comment: I would test that yes, try to use the both ways. That is of course if you don't want to refactor you old icons.